# What would be the best way to share state between a Vanilla JavaScript using jQuery and React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm involve in the migration of a large single page app all written in Vanilla JavaScript and heavily relaying on jQuery over to React 18. The goal is to replaces pieces of the UI with newer React Components one section at a time.

So far it's going well but I'm wondering what the best way to share state (data) between the older parts of the application (built with jQuery) with the newer React Components.

I've seen some information on Redux as a possible solution, although I've never used it before and
I do not know if this might be over kill.

Keep in mind this working mostly because like I said it was always written as a Single Page App (SPA).

So I'm looking for suggestions and advice on how to do this correctly.

Comment: You may use CustomEvent as an _umbrella_ tool to wrap vanilla and React parts of your app.

Comment: Interesting, and this  would allow the two parts to communicate?